# SSMS on Windows 11 not showing results grid

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I just upgraded to Windows 11 Pro and installed the latest SSMS (18.12.1). When I right click a table and choose "Select top 1000 rows" the results are shown per usual. When I right click and choose "Edit top 200 rows" the results tab is blank. No grid, no query, nothing. Just a blank tab.
[image]
I've checked Tools>Options>General and "results to grid" is selected. I've also checked Tools>Options>Results To Grid, and "discard results after execution" is UNCHECKED. I've reinstalled SSMS, installed previous versions down to V17, but still no luck. Has anyone come across this issue? What am I missing?

Comment: What version of SQL Server..? I don't don't nlthis is another person trying to use SSMS 18, rather than 19, with SQL Server 2022. As I've said to the last 4/5 people, just don't use the feature anyway; it's buggy, quirky and flawed.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. It's SQL Server 2022. I just uninstalled v18 of SSMS and installed the preview v19 of SSMS and that seems to have done the trick. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per Larnu's answer, I installed the preview version 19 of SSMS and it resolved the issue. Thanks